# Infinite light in Blender (like c4d)?

Tags: lighting

One thing I miss coming from Cinema 4d is the Infinite light. Is there a similar light in Blender? If not, is there a way to do something similar?

For those of you who don't know, the Infinite light doesn't depend on position (doesn't matter where you put it). Instead, in order to change the lighting you change the rotation of the light.

https://youtu.be/StPAPmZN5gg?t=273

Thanks for any help!

Comment: it sound like Sun in Blender, only rotation matters, not location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is most likely the sun light: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/lights/light_object.html?highlight=light#sun-light